# Reemplazar una ruta con regex. Error: "character to be escaped is missing"

Tags: java, regex, rutas

Tengo un programa que detecta cada vez que un archivo nuevo se crea, y quiero copiar dicho archivo a una nueva ubicación.

Mi problema es que no se cómo hacer para quitar el trozo `C:\Archive` y suprimirlo por la nueva ubicación.

```java
ruta = ruta.replaceFirst("C:\\\\Archive\\\\*", "E:\\");
```

Estoy probando con esto, pero me da un error:

> ```
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: character to be escaped is missing
> ```

Intento que, por ejemplo, los textos:

```
C:\Archive
C:\Archive\carpeta\archivo.ej
```

Se reemplacen por:

```
E:\
E:\carpeta\archivo.ej
```

¿Alguna ayuda?
Gracias.

Comment: No se entiende bien lo que quieres hacer. ¿Reemplazar, suprimir...? ¿Que tal si pones por separado, quiero reemplazar o suprimir de esta cadena esto por esto? Los otros \\\ y el * en tu cadena se prestan a confusión, no se sabe si son parte de tu cadena original o parte de tu intento de regex

Comment: Hola @pitiklan - Me tomé la libertad de modificar tu pregunta con la intención de que quede más claro lo que estás preguntando. Si hay algo que no sea tal cual estabas intentando hacerlo, no dudes en [edit] o comentarlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La expresión regular que estás intentando está perfecta.

El problema está en el texto de reemplazo. Hay que escapar la `\`.

> En [`String.replaceFirst()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) se menciona:
>
> Tenga en cuenta que las barras (`\`) y los signos pesos (`$`) en el texto de reemplazo pueden causar que los resultados sean diferentes a lo que sería un texto literal.

**Código**

```java
ruta = ruta.replaceFirst("^C:\\\\Archive(?:\\\\+|$)", "E:\\\\");
//            escapado con 4 barras por cada una literal ^^^^
```

Además modifiqué unos detalles:

- Agregué `^` para que sólo coincida al inicio del texto.
- Modifiqué el final del regex para que no coincida con `C:\Archivero2`

Demo: http://ideone.com/Dy4gOi

---

Adicionalmente, si quisieras asegurarte que cualquier texto de reemplazo sea tomado como literal, se puede utilizar el método [`Matcher.quoteReplacement()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement(java.lang.String)).

**Código**

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
```

```java
String ruta  = "C:\\Archive\\carpeta\\archivo.ej";
String regex = "^C:\\\\Archive(?:\\\\+|$)";
String reemp = "E:\\";
System.out.println("Ruta: " + ruta);

ruta = ruta.replaceFirst(regex, Matcher.quoteReplacement(reemp));
//escapar caracteres especiales ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
System.out.println("Reemplazada: " + ruta);
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/TUgQEh

---

> **¿Por qué hay que escapar cada barra con 4 barras?**
>
> En Java, una barra `\` sirve como [secuencia de escape de caracteres
>   literales](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6) como `\n`. `\t`, etc. Por eso, una barra literal se debe
>   escribir como `"\\"`. Es decir, son 2 barras por cada 1 literal.
>
> Además, ¡la barra también funciona como escape para regex!
>   Principalmente, sirve para escapar los `$` que de lo contrario
>   tendrían un significado especial. Por ejemplo, se usaría si capturamos
>   texto entre paréntesis y lo usamos en el reemplazo como `$1`
>   ([demo](http://rextester.com/GHYC10857)). Pero para reemplazar por un signo `$` literal, se debe
>   escapar con una barra como `\$` ([demo](http://rextester.com/WECSJL60497)).
>
> Entonces, por cada barra en el texto de reemplazo:
>
> - Son 2 barras para que Java lo interprete como secuencia de escape.
> - Son 2 barras para que regex lo tome como literal.
> - **4 barras en total**.

Comment: Gracias, justamente era esto lo que buscaba. No tengo muy claro, porque si mi ruta es E:\, tengo que "escapar" con 4 \, cuando sólo es una la contrabarra.

Comment: @pitiklan Me alegro que te haya sido útil. Agregué más información en la respuesta. Avisame si hay algo que aún no se entiende