# Que se supone que hace esta Expresión Regular?. /^(000\.000\.|000\.100\.1|000\.[36])/

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, oracle-sqldeveloper

En mi trabajo hay un servicio que devuelve unos códigos y ya me da esa expresión, pero no logro entender lo que hace. un ejemplo de los códigos que se supone que son correctos es: 000.000.100 (successful request).
PEro he probado esa expresión en java y me devuelve false entonces no se qué hacer.

Comment: En java por cada diagonal invertida que tiene esa expresión regular tu debes poner dos diagonales invertidas. Es decir, en vez de `\ ` va `\\ `. Otra cosa que detecto es que la diagonal del principio y la del final no van en java. Esas diagonales están porque así es la sintaxis de javascript, pero al ponerlas en java no van.

Comment: Puedes verificar la expresión regular que estás obteniendo en [RegExr.com](https://regexr.com). En todo caso, sería bueno que te documentaras un poco sobre las expresiones regulares, sobre todo si es parte de tu trabajo. Saludos

Comment: Por otra parte, tal como indica @abrahamhs, la expresión regular de tu pregunta es un literal en JavaScript. Para usarla en Java debes usar el constructor adecuado. Si mal no recuerdo se usa la clase [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). Saludos

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: @MauricioContreras estas equivocado. En java `\ ` significa secuencia de escape de strings, `\\ ` es secuencia de escape para regex. Por lo tanto `\. ` es un punto como expresion regex. Si quieres usar punto como caracter en expresión regex hay que hacer esto `\\. `. Si no me crees revisa las citas de [esta publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/51186/3834).

Comment: @abrahamhs, tienes toda la razón, elimino mi comentario previo. Gracias

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos, si lo de las dos contrabarras \\ se me ponía sola cuando lo intentaba hacer con una, y si tendré que informarme más sobre esto tienes razón. Ahora me pondré a mirar documentación, buen día, Saludos Óscar.